# Manipulating Django form to show the correct validation error(s)

Tags: django, django-forms

In a Django form, I'm getting users to input their usernames. The field is like so:

```
username = forms.RegexField(max_length=50,regex=re.compile('^[\w.@+-]+$'),\
        error_messages={'invalid': _("(tip: only use alphabets, numbers or @ _ . + - symbols)")})
```

Later, in the `clean_username` method, I also need to ensure users didn't include a whtiespace in the username. I do that like so:

```
def clean_username(self):
    username = self.cleaned_data['username']
    if ' ' in username:
        raise ValidationError("(tip: a username can't have whitespaces)")
    return username
```

The problem is that this validation error never appears, since whitespaces fail the prior regex check. I need to be able to show the whitespace related ValidationError separately. Moreover I also don't want to compromise on showing the relevant error if a user writes a regex failing username such as `Bèndèr*`.

What's the best way to fix this issue? An illustrative example would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So instead of using the `RegexField` I would probably either go with a `CharField` and a customized `clean`-method for the field, which handles the whitespace issue first and only checks the regex if the the whitespace check passed.

Or I would use a `CharField` and assign a [custom validator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/validators/#writing-validators) first, that checks for the whitespaces, and additionally a [`RegexValidator`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/validators/#regexvalidator)

Something along these lines:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator

def validate_whitespaces(value):
    if ' ' in value:
        raise ValidationError("Oops, a whitespace error occured.")

username = forms.CharField(
    max_length=50,
    validators=[
        validate_whitespaces,
        RegexValidator(
            regex='^[\w.@+-]+$',
            message='Only use valid chars ...'
        )
    ]
)
```

Comment: Thanks arie. Yea, I suspected so. But one clarification needed: would I lose anything else by replacing `RegexField` with `CharField`? As in, why does a `RegexField` event exist, given a regexvalidation can easily be called in a CharField anyway? I'm trying to be extra careful here since this relates to my app's auth flow - don't want to be bitten by anything unforeseen. The official documentation for a `RegexField` seems pretty benign though.

Comment: You can check the the source of the `RegexField`: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/fields.py#L493
There is not much more going on than passing the regex, which is defined on the field, to the validator.